# python calculate min/max, std for a time series

Tags: python, pandas

my dataset is like,

date          time             product   value1  value2 value3

2015-10-01    09:00:00.000     P1         1       2       3

2015-10-01    10:00:00.000     P1         2       3       4

2015-10-01    11:00:00.000     P1         5       6       7

2015-10-01    09:00:00.000     P2         1       2       3

2015-10-01    10:00:00.000     P2         2       3       4

2015-10-01    11:00:00.000     P2         5       6       7

..

..

2015-10-02    09:00:00.000     P1         1       2       3

2015-10-02    10:00:00.000     P1         2       3       4

2015-10-02    11:00:00.000     P1         5       6       7

2015-10-02    09:00:00.000     P2         1       2       3

2015-10-02    10:00:00.000     P2         2       3       4

2015-10-02    11:00:00.000     P2         5       6       7

there are  10 different type of products. we call it P1, P2, P3, P4,....P10
I want to calculate Min/Max, mean, std  of  value1/2/3   for given product(say P1)
in a range of datetime(say from 2015-10-01  11:00:00.000 to 2015-10-02 10:00:00.000)

Thanks for your help！

Comment: What have you already tried, and how did it fail to do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `date` and `time` are two columns of strings. If that's the case, I would create a timestamp column and then filter. Finally, you can `groupby` product and then aggregate. (Assuming your data is in a pandas dataframe `df`. `np` is numpy)

```
df['datetime'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])

print df[df['datetime'].between(pd.Timestamp('2015-10-01 11:00:00.000'),pd.Timestamp('2015-10-02 10:00:00.000'))].groupby(['product'])[['value1', 'value2', 'value3']].agg([min, max, np.mean, np.std])
```

Comment: it works beautifully! Thank you so much. Another question, is it possible I can do SQL type of operation in pandas? For example,  select * from pd where product in (P1, P2) and value1 >100

Comment: `df[df['product'].isin(['P1','P2') & (df['value1']>100)]`